# close React Dialog with a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dialog, material-ui

I want to open the diaglog when the screen is visited so I set the default state to true. I made a custom button. When I click on it, the state should change to false and the dialog should close. However, the dialog doesnt close. What am I doing wrong and how else can I close the dialog?

```
<Dialog open={openReminder}>
  <DialogTitle>Reminder</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText>Don't forget to take your daily walk!</DialogContentText>
    <div className={classes.reminderContainer}>
      <DialogButton
        text={"Ok, thanks!"}
        onPress={() => setOpenReminder(false)}
      />
    </div>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

```
export const DialogButton = ({ onPress, text }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button onPress={onPress} className={classes.button}>
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `onPress` as a prop in DialogButton? Can you add your code from this component aswell?

Comment: Do you mean `onClick` instead of `onPress`?

Comment: Mixed it with React Native, oops @NearHuscarl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the onPress event try using onClick,

```
 <Button onClick={onPress} className={classes.button}>
  {text}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things which I note :

1. You need to change onPress to OnClick inside  like this :

   ```
   <Button onClick={onPress} className={classes.button}>
    {text}
   </Button>
   ```
2. Check inside your Dialog component that you explicitly hide it when 'open' prop is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DialogButton text={"Ok, thanks!"} onPress={()=>setOpenReminder(!openReminder)}/>

<Button onClick={onPress} className={classes.button}>
 {text}
</Button>
```

Comment: Change setOpenReminder(!openReminder)} so that it will work vice-versa (true/false) and in button use onClick event. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the onPress with onClick in your child component like this.

```
<Button onClick={onPress} className={classes.button}>
      {text}
</Button>
```

check out if it works.